# How to program arduino for ethernet with only usb cable

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading, ethernet

I have arduino UNO r3 ATMEGA 328P board and [this](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/TypeB-USB-cable-for-Arduino-Diecimila-and-Freeduino-p-130.html) kind of a cable. But I want to make and test a program that need to get the data through ethernet port. Can I do only with them. I want to know whether they are enough to that (there are any converter or virtual devices) or should I buy anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the programming of the Arduino through the USB cable, but in order to test and operate the program, you'll need an Ethernet shield and a cable to connect that to the LAN.